# Limit Comment Number Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Following is my code which I am using to display comments of posts in a loop (Custom Post Types). I would like to display only the latest 3 comments. Kindly help me to limit comments.

```
<?php  foreach (get_comments() as $comment): ?>
    <div><span class="author-name"><?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?> said:</span> <span class="author-cmnt">"<?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?>".</span></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only additional code you need to add is having a limiter for the `foreach`. [get_comments](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/) can be supplied some arguments like `number` through an array.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'number'  => '3',
);

$comments = get_comments($args); ?>

<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>
  <div><span class="author-name"><?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?> said:</span> 
  <span class="author-cmnt">"<?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?>".</span></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is the output that I get:

[image: Last 3 comments]

Comment: This code is running in a loop. So when I pasted the same, it shows me same comments every-time.

Comment: But I tested it. It shows different and recent comments in my blog. Just check the screenshot.

Comment: I just had to add the ID in array. It worked. Thanks. @m4n0